# Can virtual function in base class be invisible?

Tags: c++

I ran the first example under 'in detail' in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual to prove the idea

> Base::vf does not need to be visible (can be declared private, or
>   inherited using private inheritance) to be overridden.

```
class B {
    virtual void do_f(); // private member
 public:
    void f() { do_f(); }; // public interface
};
struct D : public B {
    void do_f() override; // overrides B::f
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    B* bp = &d;
    bp->f(); // calls D::do_f();
}
```

But compiler reported error: http://cpp.sh/5hk6v

```
/tmp/ccNhIT1Y.o: In function `main':
:(.text.startup+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for D'
:(.text.startup+0x10): undefined reference to `D::do_f()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(I have chosen C++14)

Is the claim wrong or there is a bug in the code?

Comment: Put the necessary code in your question, not in a link.

Comment: **−1** The code and compiler invocation not provided. Anyway, the claim is correct, and the problem is either in the code, or with the compiler, or  your interpretation, or some mix of this.

Comment: Private members are still visible, so that quote is quite misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you posted is more of an example of concept, not complete ready-to-build code.

You declare `D::do_f` but nowhere define it. Add at least an empty body, and it will build without error. (As noted in @Peter's comment, the listed errors actually come from the linker, not compiler.)

```
struct D : public B {
    void do_f() override {} // overrides B::f
};
```

Comment: The errors are actually from the linker, not from compilation.